# Suppress Firefox/Firebug SHA-1 warning

Tags: firefox, firebug, sha

I use Firebug for web development. Since version Firefox 37 I see the following annoying message in my console:

> This site makes use of a SHA-1 Certificate; it's recommended you use certificates with signature algorithms that use hash functions stronger than SHA-1"

I understand that it is an important message, but it is duplicated many times and makes my work almost impossible.
Moreover, it appears every time my page communicates with other pages, for example with Google Analytics and other counters. So if I were to update my certificate, this message would still appear because these sites would have SHA-1.
So any site with GA gives me trouble.

How can I disable or filter this message?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

you can get rid of the message, but you have to modify firebugs code.

Sorry forgot to mention you need to convert the .xpi to .zip and extract the files first. You can leave the folder as is when done or zip it and convert it to an xpi again. You will need to restart Firefox.

1. locate the pluggin in your firefox profile dirctor and go to this file "\extensions\firebug@software.joehewitt.com\content\firebug\console\errors.js".
2. search for "logScriptError: function(context, object, isWarning)".
3. After the code "var error = new ErrorMessageObj(object.errorMessage, object.sourceName, object.lineNumber, object.sourceLine, category, context, null);".

input the following code:

```
if(error.message.indexOf('SHA-1') != -1 || error.message.indexOf('Security Policy') != -1){
            return false;
        }
```

should be about line 330.

Comment: If you are leaving the folder extracted, you will also need to delete the .xpi file

Comment: I would have to do this update each time I update my Firebug though. Nonetheless +1 for this.

Comment: you may need to go in to "about:config" and change, "xpinstall.signatures.required" to false because of firefox starting to require signatures. I'm running on a fresh install of windows and everything and can confirm i got it working, but i'm not sure if it's because i have that setting set to false.

Comment: Note that this answer is for the Firebug plugin (which is discontinued). This answer won't work for the Firefox's built-in developer console. I hope my comment can save any unnecessary hassles.

Answer (score 29):

As [stated in the Firebug discussion group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/firebug/bRihH3JG9Q0/olRo_E8AM-sJ), Firebug's *Console* panel currently (Firebug 2.x) **cannot** filter single messages out. You can only filter by messages matching a specific text using the [search field](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Search_Field).

There are enhancement requests like [issue #4507](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/issues/4507) reported to add such a filter, though it is unlikely that this will get implemented in Firebug, especially not in version 2.x, directly.

Firebug 3 will integrate into the built-in DevTools, which allow you to filter those warnings by unchecking *Warnings* within the *Security* menu inside the *Console* panel:

[image: Disable security warnings within the *Console* panel of the built-in DevTools]

Besides that I created [bug 1170476](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1170476) asking to reduce the messages to a minimum.

**Update:**

[Firebug development is discontinued](https://blog.getfirebug.com/2016/06/07/unifying-firebug-firefox-devtools/). Instead, there is a Firebug theme available within the Firefox DevTools starting from Firefox 48. Bug 1170476 is fixed since Firefox 42, so you will only see one message logged with a [counter showing how often the message occurred](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1170476#c21).

Comment: Update is, Firebug is dead and bug 1170476 is fixed. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Oh no why did they end Firebug??

Comment: Basically, [too few resources](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/graphs/contributors) to compete with the built-in browser devtools, shortly mentioned in the [latest blog post about the merge](https://blog.getfirebug.com/2016/06/07/unifying-firebug-firefox-devtools/).

Comment: Wow I am never going to get over that. Never been a fan of the in built tools especially Chrome

Answer (score 6):

Select the Console tab and, keeping pressed *Ctrl* on the keyboard, click on *Errors*, *Info*, *Debug Info*, *Cookies*.

Bear in mind that this will disable the output of all the warnings logged in Firebug and not only the ones generated by googleapis.

Comment: I've tried that. Unfortunately this also disables console.log() output (which is rather suprising; moreso, it can't be found in any of the groups except of "All", although I expect that to appear in "Info" or "Debug Info").

Answer (score 0):

Remove HTTPS from the URL or keep all resources local.

Comment: For just a simple localhost client for pure local running JS - perfect. Didn't see it swapped to https out of nowhere.