# How to prevent Firebug 2 spewing out SHA-1 certificate warnings in the console

Tags: firefox, ssl, firebug

Recently my local development environment has been spewing out these messages in the ***Firebug 2*** console:

> This site makes use of a SHA-1 Certificate; it's recommended you use
>   certificates with signature algorithms that use hash functions
>   stronger than SHA-1.

Is there any way to remove them?

This is only a concern for my local development site, which, obviously, I have full access to change. SHA-1 warnings on external sites I can live with.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30589219/suppress-firefox-firebug-sha-1-warning

Comment: @JiriS It looks like the other answer is for Firebug 3 - which is still in Beta.

Comment: Note that there won't be any new features integrated into Firebug 2. So you either need to switch to the built-in DevTools (and maybe use Firebug 3 on top of them) or live with this issue. I enhanced [my answer to the similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30590749/432681) to reflect that.