# how to get rid of Firefox SHA 1 certificate error

Tags: wordpress, firefox

My Firefox browser gives "This site makes use of a SHA-1 Certificate; it's recommended you use certificates with signature algorithms that use hash functions stronger than SHA-1." error message in Firebug console every time  I open a web page. How to get ride from this error while using the Firebug

Comment: Is this your website or an arbitrary website? If it's not your website, then that website needs to upgrade to SHA-2, there won't be anything you can do about it. If it's your website, then you need to tag which web server/languages/frameworks you are using so that we can help.

Comment: Many of them is my own site. Site is developed in WordPress 4.2 and are hosted on Godday and Bluehost servers.

Comment: I've added the wordpress tag. In the future, all the information in your above comment should be included in the question; otherwise, it isn't clear how it is even programming related.

Comment: May be your office network is causing the issue?Try to access the site outside your office network. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get a new certificate from your host. We are in a transitional period where older certificates are often SHA-1, but newer certificates will likely be SHA-2.

For GoDaddy you need to Re-Key your certificate
https://www.godaddy.com/help/rekey-certificate-4976:

1. List item
2. Log in to your Account Manager.
3. Click SSL Certificates.
4. Next to the certificate you want to use, click Manage.
5. Next to the certificate you want to use, in the Actions column, click View Status.
6. Click Manage.
7. Click Re-Key certificate.
8. In the Certificate Signing Request (CSR) field, paste your new CSR, including ----BEGIN NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST---- and ----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST----.
9. Click Save.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the cert is probably a good idea. Another solution if using firebug, look at my post here. [Suppress Firefox/Firebug SHA-1 warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30589219/suppress-firefox-firebug-sha-1-warning/31494521#)

Answer (score 0):

Try to keep all resources(JS CSS etc) local or remove HTTPS from the resource URL.
Keep only HTTP protocol. Its because of secured HTTP protocol