# Remove SHA-1 warnings Firebug

Tags: firefox, firebug

I'm testing a project on localhost but I get a lot of SHA-1 warnings in my firebug console. Warnings like:

```
This site makes use of a SHA-1 Certificate; it's recommended you use certificates with signature algorithms that use hash functions stronger than SHA-1.
```

Now I found this link to surpress them:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31494521/3599496

So I tried to do it, but when I edited the .xpi and placed the newly .xpi in the right folder (compress the folder with .zip, change .zip into .xpi) and I reopen Firefox, it'll remove the .xpi and Firebug is gone.

Now somebody else gave me his .xpi file which has this fixed, but now it works for a little while but after a time the warnings return.

Any way I can fix this? It's really annoying as I need to be able to view a POST and I have to find my POST through a list of 9 million SHA-1 warnings.

I downloaded the latest Firebug (2.0.13) and I use Firefox 41.0.2

Still haven't figured out the problem. I tried a few times putting the .xpi but after a certain time the warnings just come back.

Comment: If Firefox removes the XPI, that's a sign that you didn't pack it correctly. You should rather only extract that one file, edit it and add it again to the XPI. I assume the bug returned because of an automatic update of Firebug.

Answer (score 1):

This issue got fixed for the Firefox DevTools in [bug 1170476](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1170476). There the message is only output once per page now.

I think this isn't fixed in Firebug yet (didn't see a page still using SHA-1 for some time). Though because Firebug 3 will be based on the Firefox DevTools, the problem will go away with that release.